# I have an iphone 4 with ios7 and I don't have any camera filters or different camera options

Tags: iphone

I updated my phone and It updated everything expect my camera. I'm not sure if my phone just isn't compatable with it because it's not an S it's just a 4. The only camera options I have is video, photo, an square. All my othe friends iphone have those and other photo optiin and they have three little colors at the bottom of the screen on the right side. Please help I need to know if my iphone just isn't able to have it like it's the wrong version or generation or if something just went wrong when updating it.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly normal. The iPhone 4 version of ios7 is lacking many features seen on the newer devices, including parallax, panorama, Siri and yes, live filters. However the filters can be applied in the photos app.

Answer (score 0):

I use an iPhone 4 too. Have the same options at the camera app. 
More options you get at photo app if you open a photo and tap on "edit". Now you have severall possibilities like color and so on.